# node js node-exec-promise.exec command to call retire.js through command line works but ends with an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, node-modules, child-process

Trying to run the command mentioned in sections below, it is intended to run retire.js on some javascript files/libraries and pipe the output in a json file. The command works and produces output in a json file but ends with an error.

When I try the same command directly by copy pasting the command in command line it works without an error.

I have tried the exexSync version and shelljs as well though get error in Shelljs as well. However, I am not able to understand what is causing the problem.

using node-exec-promise.exec :

```
exec('node C:/Users/walee/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/retire/bin/retire --outputformat json --outputpath D:/Internship/local/testing/1.json').
                            then(function(retire_out){
                                console.log('Retire Command Success ');
                                console.log(' Retire_out Result  ',retire_out);
                                return retire_out;
                                }, function(err){
                                 console.error(err)
                            }
```

Using Shelljs:

```
   if (shell.exec('node 
   C:/Users/walee/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/retire/bin/retire --outputformat json --outputpath D:/Internship/local/testing/1.json').code !== 0) {

    shell.echo('Error: Git commit failed');
    shell.exit(1);
  }
```

Expected Result is a Json file with known vulnerabilities found by retire.js, the file gets populated and it has valid json.

However, I get the following error in command line:

```
{ Error: Command failed: node C:/Users/walee/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/retire/bin/retire --outputformat json --outputpath D:/Internship/local/testing/1.json

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 13,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   'node C:/Users/walee/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/retire/bin/retire --outputformat json --outputpath D:/Internship/local/testing/1.json' }
```

Comment: retire.js exits with exit code 13 (can be changed) when vulnerabilities are found - this is expected behaviour

Comment: @JaromandaX however it doesn't give this code when I run retire via command line.

Comment: And I think the command should not fail since vulnerabilities were found which is the purpose of retire.js.

Comment: I bet it does exit with exit code 13 - how are you testing for exit code on the command line? It's up to you to handle the exit code as required

Comment: by the way, running `retire` with an outputpath specified will mean that there will be no output except to the file specified - therefore, even if the error code wasn't 13, your code would still not get anything in `retire_out`

Comment: what you'll want to do is ... a) `exec('.....').catch(err => {check if exit code is 13, if not then throw err}).then(() => { read the output file if you want to display it here }).catch(err => { handle other errors here})`

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you, your first answer was a light-bulb,  I am checking for it via  a function of err but I think catch approach might be better. I will get back here once I get somewhere.

Comment: @JaromandaX how do I select your comment as an answer .

Comment: function execute_command(cmd,filename, outputpath)
    {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            spawn.exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            }).on('exit', code => {
                console.log('final exit code is', (code));
                console.log(typeof(code));
                if(code === 13)
              

I did the above approach.

Comment: You can't - I haven't posted an answer - I can post one now if you like, it may help others in the future I guess

Comment: It will indeed. Thank you and I cannot up vote your answer since I am a new user and my reputation is very low at the moment.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer (if it's correct)

Comment: By the way, the `node-exec-promise` "library" (it's like 20 lines of code, so ...) is flawed in that it only gives you access to `stderr` in the case of a non-zero exit code - it is extremely easy to write a "better" version of it - though, as I said, in this case it wouldn't make a difference since the JSON is written to a file, not stdout/stderr

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: I cannot accept the answer , I am a newbie :)

Comment: really? I thought you had to wait before accepting. Seriously, I don't know, never asked a question!

Answer (score 0):

Because `retire` exits with an exitcode of 13 if there are vulnerabilities found, you'll want a `.catch` before any `.then` to "allow" exitcode 13.

Also, since you've specified `--outputpath` for `retire`, the output will NOT go to stdout, so you will need to read the outputfile in the `.then` code - also, since retire would return an "error" (13) - node-exec-promise doesn't even give you access to stdout/stderr in the `err` that is passed to the `.catch` code anyway!

The following is pseudo-code, since I'm not fully familiar with node-exec-promise:

```
exec('node C:/Users/walee/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/retire/bin/retire --outputformat json --outputpath D:/Internship/local/testing/1.json')
.catch(err => {
    if (err.code !== 13) {
        throw err;
    }
})
.then(() => {
    // read the output file if you want to display it here 
})
.catch(err => { 
    //handle other errors here
});
```